# Executing Mongo query db.collection.runCommand("text",{"search":"search text"})

Tags: c#, mongodb, c#-4.0

I need to add full text search option in my site, database in mongodb,
Mongo Query:

```
db.collection.runCommand("text",{"search":"search text"})
```

Gives result, but how to execute it using C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
var commandResult = collection.RunCommand(aggregationCommand);
var response = commandResult.Response;
foreach (BsonDocument result in response["results"].AsBsonArray)
{
    // process result
}
```

fine example but with aggregate can be found here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/8dM1LnHh9-Q

Comment: Thanks for reply, but you can see, in runCommand first parameter only "text" without value, so how can i set in aggregation command.

Comment: that was only an example, you should be able to use your `"text",{"search":"search text"}` within RunCommand()

Comment: Thanks, but i dont know how to use it, please help me with example what i need, please.

Comment: The mongo shell runCommand converts invocation into the equivalent of `db.collection.runCommand({ "text" : "collection", "search" : "search text" })`.

Comment: The new structure that comes back as a result contains results by scores. So the above code will deserialize the wrong BSON document (the code doesn't fail but resulted docs are incorrect). See @mmmdreg answer to get more up to date answer.

Comment: Also there is no result collection in response, there's a typo, the collection is "results", edited this answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
_collection.Insert(new BsonDocument("x", "The quick brown fox"));  

var textSearchCommand = new CommandDocument
{
  { "text", _collection.Name },
  { "search", "fox" }
};
var commandResult = _database.RunCommand(textSearchCommand);
var response = commandResult.Response;

Assert.AreEqual(1, response["stats"]["nfound"].ToInt32());
Assert.AreEqual("The quick brown fox", response["results"][0]["obj"]["x"].AsString);
```

Source: [Mongo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/MongoDB.DriverUnitTests/MongoCollectionTests.cs#L1606)

Answer (score 3):

I cannot find `CommandDocument` in [MongoDb.Driver 2.4.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/2.4.4) but `JsonCommand` worked.

```
var ru = db.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(new MongoDB.Driver.JsonCommand<BsonDocument>("{getLastRequestStatistics: 1}"));
```

Answer (score 1):

My rather general runCommand's shell-to-c# conversion rule goes something like this:

```
db.runCommand( <command's json> )
```

corresponds to

```
var res = database.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(CommandDocument.Parse("<command's json text>"));
```