# Execute mongo db shell query from c# mongo db driver (latest)

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to run below mongo query from C#. Currently I am using mongodb C# driver 2.7

```
db.changelog.find({}).forEach(function(doc){
//make javascript object dynimacally 
var newDoc = {
    "key": "value",
    "doc": doc
}
db.changelog_log.insertOne(newDoc); })
```

This is successfully run into mongo shell, now I want to execute that script from c# application with modify object value dynamically. I was hoping it would be able to parse those queries and pass them off to database.RunCommand but I have not been able to make any progress.

```
var bsonDoc = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>("query");
database.RunCommand(command);
```

That code fails on the call to Deserialize with this error message: [Additional information: JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'db'.] which makes perfect sense because the script is not valid JSON.

After mongo 3.0 eval function has been depreciated.
So I'm having trouble parsing the script into something that can be executed.

Need help.

Thanks

Comment: The "mongo query" is actually a mongo shell **script** - a program that uses shel javascript helper functions. In this particular script it makes a `find` query to the server, retrieve a cursor, iterates it  and makes 1 `insert` query per each retrieved document. You can achieve the same result with single aggregation query, or translate the script from shell js to c#.

Comment: Can you provide an example for this (translate the script from shell js to c#) simple one to get started with driver.

Comment: Unfortunately not, if I knew c# I'd answer instead of commenting.

Comment: What's the current C# code that you use?

Comment: Have you tried using JsonCommand like this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44575855/3621336

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69190997/mongo-c-how-can-i-execute-string-as-mongo-query