# Mongo. C#. How can i execute string as mongo query

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongo-shell

Let's say I have a string. " db.getCollection("somecollection").find({})". Can I execute this string as a query in C#? i.e. I get a string. And I just execute it as a query but in c#

I just want like this

```
string query = "db.getCollection("somename")";
Mongo.execute(query);
```

Comment: define your complete scenario what have you done for this  .technically this is not supported but  for this you can run direct mongo commands in c# to obtain results

Comment: i've just updated post. check please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, the best you can do in this context is to use `db.RunCommand<BsonDocument>("{ ping : 1 }")` (c#) which is close to the shell `db.runCommand({ ping : 1 })`

**UPDATE**:
you may look at this as well [How to execute mongo commands through shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837673/how-to-execute-mongo-commands-through-shell-scripts), I'm not familiar with this and it doesn't work for me on windows and 5.0 server in most of the cases mentioned there other than simple one: `mongo --eval "printjson(db.serverStatus())"`, but if you will be able to make this suggested script `mongo < script.js` (or similar) work in, for example, the shell, you will be able to put your random query in this file(`script.js`) and then, add this file as argument into Process creating similar to:

```
            using (var process = new Process())
            {
                // arguments below may require the whole path to the files
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = "script.js";
                process.StartInfo.FileName = "mongo"; 

                process.Start();
            }
```

to read results, you will need analyzing `process.StandardOutput`/`process.StandardError` stream.

Comment: But there must be a way to do it.

Comment: Mongo doesn't provide any other way other than runCommand, you can reach this goal via reflection or codedom: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/using-the-codedom, but it will require additional steps

Comment: however if I understood what you need correctly, runCommand https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/ mostlikely is what you need

Comment: runCommand require JSON format as string.

Comment: it requires a MQL command in BSON format. It can be BsonDocument or string.

Comment: I tried to make a runCommand ("db. getCollection ("dbName")") with interpolation, but it swears that the string is not in the right format.

Comment: yes, because it expects MQL command. You still didn't provide a use case why you need this

Comment: I get a string. And I am sure that there is a mong o request in it. I just have to execute this mongo request. Like this string result = Mongo.execute("db.getCollection('name')");

Comment: there is a mongo shell command, not MQL request, it's different things

Comment: how can i execute mongo shell command? as above in c#.

Comment: you can't do it for exactly above query

Comment: you still didn't provide details why you need this. `string result = Mongo.execute("db.getCollection('name')")` this string cannot return any result since it will be just a mongo object

Comment: It's just example. Query maybe like this: Mong.execute("db.getCollection('somedb').find({})"); I have to execute this string as mongo query. Is there any some way do it?

Comment: again, it's not possible with exactly code you use. The best you can do is to use `runCommand`. In shell this command will look like: `db.runCommand({find : "collectionName" , filter : {}})`. In c# you will need to use: `db.RunCommand<BsonDocument>({find : "collectionName" , filter : {}})`. The doc: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/find/

Comment: ok, thank you. Just i am getting arbitrary string. That will be mongo query but in string. And i must execute it. I dont know what string will be. I have to execute it. I cannot transform string to bsondocument, dont know what is in string

Comment: see my update above

Comment: hi, i know this way) I worked by this way, but it's not security way) I am finding a way, that will work only in C#. Without working with shell. But thank you for finding answers for me)