# How to run js script mongo command using MongoDB Driver in .net6?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, mongodb, asp.net-core

Is there any way to run js script (mongo command) using MongoDB Driver in .net 6? I've tried to run `db.RunCommand<BsonDocument>` but it does not work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: do you mean commands like this?https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.aggregate

Comment: no, it's not possible, see my answer here with some details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69190997/mongo-c-how-can-i-execute-string-as-mongo-query/69200520#69200520. note: `RunCommand` allows running only a single command in `mongo query language` MQL form, it's not js.

Comment: Could you add detail about the script, where it lives, and what you need it to do?   Off the cuff I'd say your .NET6 code could exec `mongosh theScript.js` as a subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

This works only for command string.

```
string command = "   {  insert: \"collection1\",     documents: [ { _id: 1, bookname: \"MongoDB\", status: \"sold\" } ]    }";
BsonDocument document = BsonDocument.Parse(command);
var result = _database.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(document);
```